# Signalr hub connection from WebAPI Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I have 2 Application hosted in 2 different Azure Machines. One is a Web form application and other a Web API 2.0 application. Both the Application share a common DLL (Lets call it Data.DLL). I have implemented Signal R HUB in the Data.DLL

In my Web App Signal R works fine as I start the hub from a javascript code.

I have added a Startup class in the WebAPI Project as well.

Now I am trying to communicate message to my clients connected to the webform application, when ever there is a PUT operation in my WebApp thought any other 3rd Party Client App.

So In my Controller Class I tried this:

```
                var ctxt = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRHub>();
                if (ctxt != null)
                {
                    try
                    { 
                        ctxt.Clients.Group("MyClients").HandleServerNotifications("Hello");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // do a thing
                    }
                }
```

But this is not working, and I am not being able to find the reason as well, as this cannot be debugged. Is this possible to achieve?

This is my Signal R Hub implementation in the Data.dll

Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

```
 Public Class SignalRHub
  Inherits Hub


 Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task 
     Dim id = Context.ConnectionId 
     Groups.Add(id , "MyClients")
     Return MyBase.OnConnected() 
 End Function


   Public Overrides Function OnDisconnected(stopCalled As Boolean) As Task 
        Return MyBase.OnDisconnected(stopCalled)
   End Function


   Public Overrides Function OnReconnected() As Task 
     Return MyBase.OnReconnected()
   End Function



    End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you can access the SignalR hub running in the WebForms application from your Web API project? It's not because they use the same DLL, they will automatically talk to each other. I think you'll need some kind of message bus between the two applications.

Comment: So using SignalR is not an option? I tried using Redis Server with a channel to communicate it over it, but that did not work either.

Comment: You can use SignalR to send messages to your client applications, but you'll need some kind of message bus to send server-to-server messages between the apps.

Comment: So when the 3rd party app does a request to the API app which should trigger an event, you send an event over a messagebus to the webforms application, which in turn uses SignalR to send an event to the web-client...

Comment: is there any example of such a message bus which i can use in my .net application

Comment: [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) f.e. or Azure ServiceBus.